# Pandas merge dataframes overwriting/replacing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a collection of identically formatted Excel spreadsheets containing current and predicted/future estimated values for a given metric.  An example format for the data is:

```
Date       Metric
2020-05-01   100
2020-06-01   150
2020-07-01   95
```

Another spreadsheet will have an identical format:

```
Date       Metric
2020-06-01   100
2020-07-01   150
2020-08-01   95
```

I would like to merge the two dataframes while preserving the earliest data as it is the most accurate and replace each following month's data with the most current estimates.  When I have tried using the `merge` function, I end up with multiple rows for future months as the estimates are appended and not replaced.

A minimal working example of what I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Data')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet_name='Data')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date'], how='outer)
```

The results from above are:

```
Date        Metric
2020-05-01   100
2020-06-01   150
2020-07-01   95
2020-06-01   100
2020-07-01   150
2020-08-01   95
```

I would like:

```
Date        Metric
2020-05-01   100
2020-06-01   100
2020-07-01   150
2020-08-01   95
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do fix

```
df=df.groupby('Date').tail(1)
         Date  Metric
0  2020-05-01     100
3  2020-06-01     100
4  2020-07-01     150
5  2020-08-01      95

df=df.iloc[::-1,:].drop_duplicates('Date')
```

Update

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Data',index_col=[0])
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet_name='Data',index_col=[0])
df1.update(df2)
```

Or

```
df=df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Comment: Does this effectively take the last value for a given date in the merged dataframe?  If so, would it be similar in function to dropping duplicates?

Comment: @Daniel yes it is same to the drop duplicate

Comment: @Daniel but you need to to reverse the order ~

Comment: Not quite - I am trying to iterate this process over a collection of spreadsheets.  I am having trouble applying your solution because I will have to start with an empty dataframe, merge new information to it, keep most current date's data, and replace future estimates while keeping past months.

Comment: I would rather not depend on dropping rows based on their location and whether they are a duplicate or not.  There could be errors, for example, if a future month is estimated to have a metric of 200, yet the actual value for that month ended up being Null.  Because there isn't a record of the Null in the dataframe, dropping duplicates will keep the estimate which ended up being wrong.  Should I fill Nulls before dropping duplicates?